Python - Extract certain values from PDFs in a folder
I am using the below code to extract text from hundreds of PDF files in a specific folder:
from pypdf import PdfReader
import os
import glob

path = input("Enter the file path: ")

pattern = path + "\\*.pdf"
result = glob.glob(pattern)

for file_name in result:
   reader = PdfReader(file_name)
   page = reader.pages[0]
   text = page.extract_text()
   print(text)

It gives me the following output:
Payslip 
March 2024  
 randomtext 
123456Name of the employee

and there are numerous lines afterwards, which are irrelevant.
What I want is, to be able to extract the employees' IDs from each document, and then use that to rename each file in the folder, on a monthly basis. The files always look exactly the same, but the name of the month and the year are changing. The employee ID can be 4-6 digits, but always in the same spot.
Is there another PDF reader library, you would use? Is it possible, to extract the digits that are always in the same spot, depending on the length, which I cannot know in advance?
The rest of the code I have, to be able to use the extracted ID number as part of the file name, but I am not sure how to take the IDs from that exact spot each month. It is a string, so I was thinking of slicing, but since the month is always changing and I cannot be sure when it will be 4, 5 or 6 digits, I gave up on that idea. The randomtext is always 9 characters, including the leading space.
Thank you in advance!
I tried slicing it but it does not work in this setting. I put the code together based on a previous code that I am using to rename PDF files in a folder, but in those cases, the ID number is always present in the filename, so it is way easier.
I finished my code (I am sorry it is not nice looking, I only do this as a hobby and to try and cut out some manual processes at work):
from pypdf import PdfReader
import os
import glob
import re

month = input("Which month's reports? Type the full name of the month: "
"(In the following format: MM_YYYY) ")
path = input("Enter the file path: ")

pattern = path + "\\*.pdf"
result = glob.glob(pattern)

try:
   for file_name in result:
      reader = PdfReader(file_name)
      page = reader.pages[0]
      text = page.extract_text()
      mylist = text.split()
      myIds = []
      myIds.append(mylist[4])
      mystring = ''.join(myIds)
      temp = re.findall(r'\d+', mystring)
      res = list(map(int, temp))
      old_name = file_name
      number = str(res)
      number = number.replace('[', '')
      number = number.replace(']', '')
      new_name = path + '\\' + number + ".Company name Payslip" + "_" + \
      month + old_name[-4:]
      os.rename(old_name, new_name)
except FileExistsError:
   print("There is a duplicate payslip for EE ID " + number + ". Delete one of their\
 payslips.")


Thanks for your answer. This would be on my company laptop, and I am not sure I could use pdftotext on it, as we cannot install stuff without elevation rights, which I do not have. This is why I wanted to stick to Python, as I have a script for quite a few other entities, but for this one, I couldn't figure out a way. Worst case, I will just work with the 3rd party who provides the documents, and ask them to send it to us with the IDs in the filename already.

Is the employee ID always in the last line of the output?

We can probably use a regex expression to match a string that starts with 4 to 6 integers and ends with a letter. That might be the best we could do in raw Python.

I now managed to split into sections in a list, and I will have the 5th part always as the ID + part of the name. Now I will just try to figure out how to take 4-6 digits from that string, as the first 4-6 characters will always be the ID.

Now, I managed to finish my code, it does not look good at all, but it works, so I am happy with it. I will put it in my original question, the only thing that happens now, is there was a duplicate file for the same ID, so then my script stopped, but in PowerShell I did see the duplicate one, so I just got rid of it and then the rest finished.
